Regarding the issue of sending getter requests for the someip function in CAPL language
Since I don't have an arXML file, I have to  defining a method:
Client:
variables
{
  DWORD gMc; // global method call handle
}
on start
{
  Initialize();
}

void Initialize()
{
  DWORD aep; // Application Endpoint handle
  DWORD csi; // consumed Service Instance handle

  // open Application Endpoint
  aep = SomeIpOpenLocalApplicationEndpoint(IP_Endpoint(TCP:192.168.0.1:50001));

  // cretae Service Instance
  csi = SomeIpCreateConsumedServiceInstance(aep,0x8001,1);

  // create method call
  gMc = SomeIpCreateMethodCall(csi,0x0001,"OnMethodResponse");
}

on key 'A'
{
  // call the getter
  SomeIpCallMethod(gMc);
}

void OnMethodResponse(dword methodCallHandle, dword messageResponseHandle )
{
  write("method resp");
}

Server:
variables
{
  DWORD gPm; // global method call handle
}

on start
{
  Initialize();
}
void Initialize()
{
  DWORD aep; // Application Endpoint handle
  DWORD psi; // consumed Service Instance handle

  // open Application Endpoint
  aep = SomeIpOpenLocalApplicationEndpoint(IP_Endpoint(TCP:192.168.0.2:50002));

  // cretae Service Instance
  psi = SomeIpCreateProvidedServiceInstance(aep,0x8001,1);

  // create method call
  gPm = SomeIpAddMethod(psi,1,"OnMethodRequest");
}

void OnMethodRequest(dword methodHandle,dword messageHandle,dword messageResponseHandle)
{
  write("method req");
}

System error：
[E] [Program / Model]   46-0503 Error in node << default >> in SomeIP_IL.dll: message with id 0x80010001 could not be serialized
I know the function used for message initialization(long SomeIpSetData(dword messageHandle, dword dataLength, byte data[] )) , but this method is getter ,No parameters,Therefore, its payload length is 0, and If the length is 0, this function cannot be used.
If you know how to solve this problem, please help me, thank you!

At present, there is only one way to solve it：
on key 'A'
{
  DWORD messageHandle = 0;
  byte buffer[16] = {0x80, 01, 00, 01, 00, 00, 00, 09, 00, 01, 00, 01, 01, 01, 00, 00};
  // call the getter
//  byte payload[1];
//  SomeIpSetData(gMc,1,payload);
//  SomeIpCallMethod(gMc);
  messageHandle = SomeIpCreateMessage(16,buffer);
  SomeIpOutputMessage(aep,IP_Endpoint(TCP:192.168.0.2:50002),messageHandle);
}

